# Select only one distinct column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I guess that is an easy question to solve, but I'm researching for an hour for it's answer.
I have a table with three columns: "id","id_x" and "name". But it's populated with repeated values, like this:

```
id  id_x    name
1   100     Name_aaa
2   100     Name_aaa
3   100     Name_aaa
4   100     Name_aaa*
5   101     Name_bbb
6   101     Name_bbb*
```

Ok, ok, I didn't create this table, and I can't modify them... I just wanna know what query I can execute to return only the values "100 - Name_aaa" and "101 - name_bbb"... Note that has an "*" after some names. I'd like to group only by the "id_x".

Is there any way to do it without using subqueries or joins?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somewhat untested, but this should do it

```
select id_x, min(name) as name
from table
group by id_x
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

> select distinct id_x , name from tablename

Comment: Hi, Nanda! Thanks for ur answer! But if I do "select distinct id_x, name from tablename" I'll get "100 - Name_aaa", "100 - Name_aaa*", "101 - Name_bbb" and "101 - Name_bbb*".

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
         id_x,
         case when name ~ E'\\*$' then substring(name, 1, length(name)-1)
              else name end
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Or](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_x) id_x, name FROM table ORDER BY id_x, name;
```

Comment: I don't think that works with all databases (just tested it and MySQL didn't like it.)

Comment: Well, the "postgresql" tag is put there for a reason.